# Convertir Anonymous type a List C#

Tags: c#, lista, linq

Estoy realizando una consulta a una base de datos y recupero algunos registros, estoy realizando una búsqueda en tiempo real a través de un textbox y funciona correctamente. Cuando recupero los datos los guardo en una lista y sobre ella realizo el filtro con Linq de la siguiente manera:

Aquí cargo los datos de la BD a una lista:

```
private List<MConductor> conductores;
conductores = VmConductores.BuscaConductores();
```

y de esta manera trato de realizar la búsqueda en dicha lista sobre los datos ya cargados:

```
GridConductores.ItemsSource = conductores.Select(
                    c => new
                    {
                        c.IdConductor,
                        c.Nombre,
                        c.ApellidoPaterno,
                        c.ApellidoMaterno,
                        c.Licencia,
                        c.LetraLicencia
                    }).
                    Where(c => c.Nombre.Contains(txtBusquedaConductores.Text)
                        || c.ApellidoMaterno.Contains(txtBusquedaConductores.Text)
                        || c.ApellidoPaterno.Contains(txtBusquedaConductores.Text)
                    );
```

Todo esto funciona pero, cuando quiero usarlos como tipo **MConductor** me marca que no se puede convertir de **Anonymous type** a **MConductor**

Como podría convertir ese objeto anónimo al tipo de mi modelo MConductor?

Anexo imagen de dónde me marca el error de IEnumerable al querer convertirlo en modelo MConductor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de un objeto anónimo crea un objeto de tipo MConductor y asignale las propiedades:

```
 conductores.Select(
               c => new MConductor
                    {
                       Idconductor = c.IdConductor,
                       Nombre      =  c.Nombre,
                       //resto de propiedades
                    })
```

Comment: Ya intenté eso pero me marca que no se puede convertir porque no implementa IEnumerable.

Comment: Añade .ToList() al final después del Where()

Comment: También intenté eso pero igual marca el error por IEnumerable

Comment: El error que muestras es porque no estás asignando las propiedades del objeto MConductor. Fíjate en el ejemplo que te di, a la izquierda va la propiedad del objeto MConductor y a la derecha el valor que se le va a asignar.

Comment: Estás en lo cierto, gracias compañero